# FatalThrowableError in Laravel Php mailer on live server

Tags: php, laravel, server, host, mailer

My laravel project php mailer function is working in local host. But in the live server it's not working:
Error:
**FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 75:
Class 'App\CustomClass\CMailer' not found**
Here is my controller file:

```
enter code here
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\CustomClass\CMailer;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


use RegistersUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array $data
 * @return User
 */
        protected function create(array $data)
        {

            $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        if ($user) {
            $mailException = null;
            $view = view('auth.verification', compact('user'))->render();
            try {
            $mail = CMailer::send('Prapti', $data['email'], 'Email verification', $view);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $mailException = true;
            }

            }

    return $user;
    }
}

enter code here
```

My class file:

```
enter code here
```

```
namespace App\CustomClass;


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

class CMailer
{
    protected static $host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    protected static $port = 468;
    protected static $encryption = 'tls';
    protected static $username = "******";
    protected static $password = '***************';
    protected static $from = '**************@gmail.com';

/**
 * Sending email by PHPMailer
 *
 * @param  string $fromName
 * @param  string $to
 * @param  string $subject
 * @param  string $message
 * @return TRUE
 */
    public static function send($fromName, $to, $subject, $message)
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = self::$host;
    // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = self::$port;
    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = self::$encryption;
    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for 
     gmail
    $mail->Username = self::$username;
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = self::$password;
    //Set who the message is to be sent from: this is sender email
    $mail->setFrom(self::$from, $fromName);
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress($to, 'Test Service');
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($message);
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        // return $mail;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

** Php mailer and class is okay. I've tested by changing port but same problem. and  not working in hosting. Where is the problem?
Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `composer dump-autoload` to reload all missing classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the same code works on your local machine, you need to run `composer du` command on the live server and include this command to your deployment script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.